# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null error

Tags: javascript, html

good day, please how can i prevent an html file from trying
to access eventListener meant for another another html file
after using window.location. both html files uses same external
js file
. thanks

my code

index.html

```
<body>

<form id=form>
    <input type="button" value="submit">
</form>

<script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
```

post.html file

```
<body>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
```

main.js file

```
document.getElementById("form").addEventListener("click", function(e){
    console.log("hello");
    window.location = "post.html";
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Well than you need to bind it via a specific id or something or add logic to see if it is on the page.....

Comment: There are a number of ways, but the easiest (and best) would be to give the elements on your two pages different identifiers (such as an ID or class). Then simply update your JavaScript to only target the unique element on the desired page. Also, your `<form>` ID needs quote marks.

Comment: i gave the form tag in the index.html file an id of form. it redirects to the post.html file but still gives the addeventlistener error

Comment: Yes, because there is no `#form` in *post.html*. So, your code would be : `var el = document.getElementById('form'); if (el) { el.addEventListener /* etc.. */ });`. Or you could check location.href.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this would be to wrap your event listener around an `if` statement that checks the pathname.

```js
if ( window.location.pathname === '/index.html' ) {
  // do stuff in here that you want to execute for the index.html page
  document.getElementById("form").addEventListener("click", function(e){
      console.log("hello");
      window.location = "post.html";
      e.preventDefault();
  });
}
```